# How to get selected row of ListView in web browser control in WPF

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a web site has a ListView and navigate it by using web browser control in WPF. I want to get selected item of ListView from web browser control. I can get selected text in web browser control by using Microsoft HTML Object Library but can't do this. Is there any way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can interop with the web browser control from WPF using the DLR features.